# Adding hover colour change to alternate link colour

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I am using:

```
a.altlink{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and:

```
class="altlink"
```

to create a seperate link colour on desired pages. What I am wondering now is how to apply a new colour when I hover on my link?

My normal links use:

```
a:hover {
    color: #C24B0C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So from this CSS I've tried:

```
a.altlink:hover{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

But this just removed the alternate link colour and reverts back to the normal link colour

How can I achieve the hover colour change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I used:

```
a:hover.altlink{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.atlink{
    color: #FFFFFF ;
}  
a:hover.atlink{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```